# No hyphenation of long words in narrow boxes

Tags: line-breaking, hyphenation

I stumbled across an hyphenation problem which I cannot explain or solve. When I use a narrow box containing a long word with a width longer than the box width, this word is not hyphenated.

The following MWE uses the long word `Rechnungsadjunktentochter` with an explicit hyphenation pattern in the preamble. This word is hyphenated in a long text, also when the break points are given in a narrow box locally, but it is not hyphenated automatically.

What happens here? And, more important, how can I get my words hyphenated automatically as expected?

**UPDATE:**
@egregs comments explain what happens. But, still, I would have to insert `\hspace{0pt}` at every first word of every paragraph of every narrow box (and I have MANY of them, partly automatically generated). How can I force TeX to hyphenate the first word of EVERY paragraph (inside an environment) automatically?

**UPDATE 2:**
The solving answer is given by the latter comments of @egreg to this question.

```
\documentclass{article}

\hyphenation{%
  Rech-nungs-ad-junk-ten-toch-ter
}

\begin{document}

\textit{Works even without the special hyphenation pattern:}\\
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla Rechnungsadjunktentochter

\bigskip
\textit{Local hyphenation pattern works as expected:}\\
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{3cm}
Rech\-nungs\-ad\-junk\-ten\-toch\-ter
\end{minipage}}

\bigskip
\textit{\bfseries Hyphenation pattern from the preamble does not work as expected:}\\
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{3cm}
Rechnungsadjunktentochter
\end{minipage}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: TeX doesn't automatically hyphenate the first word of a paragraph; just insert `\hspace{0pt}` before it so that it's not (TeXnically) the first word any more.

Comment: @egreg Would you like to turn your comment into an answer? Can I force TeX to hyphenate the first word automatically for every paragraph inside my narrow box ... maybe, be redefining `\par` (?)

Comment: I've pointed to another question where the problem is basically the same

Comment: @egreg Thank you for your help which explains what happens. I did not know that. Nevertheless, your linked answer does not solve my problem totally, since now I have to add `\hspace{0pt}` before every first word in every paragraph inside the box manually. That's better than to hyphenate manually. But is there no automatic way?

Comment: One way to avoid having to insert `\hspace{0pt}` at the start of every narrow-measure paragraph would be to switch from pdfLaTeX to LuaLaTeX. Lua(La)TeX has no problems with hyphenating the first word of a paragraph.

Comment: `\everypar=\expandafter{\the\everypar\hspace{0pt}}`

Comment: @egreg I fear, this does not work. The first paragraph is hyphenated but the next paragraph is not hyphenated.

Comment: @Mico At the moment, I have to stay with pdfLaTeX. I'm a little bit surprised that such a basic question cannot be solved with pdfLaTeX :-(

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm `minipage` acts on `\everypar`, unfortunately. A first approximation is `\everypar=\expandafter{\the\everypar\everypar{\hspace{0pt}}\hspace{0pt}}` (but this is only for `minipage`.

Comment: @egreg Yes, that's it! Thank you! Since I had this problem with a `minipage`, this solves my problem. I played a little bit around and found that `\everypar={\hspace{0pt}}` alone also works (on the cost of any predefined values). By the way, I still think that I didn't ask a duplicate question and that you finally provided another solution than you gave before on the other question. I would accept your comment as an answer :-)

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm - The inability of TeX engines prior to pdfTeX to hyphenate the very first word of a paragraph has been known for a long time. Fixing this issue required a major revision of the underlying engine...